# Java check todays date is biweekly tuesday

Tags: java

I have a couple of requirement, I need to validate if today's date is matching with a condition and if true create records in DB.

but the condition is something like this - biweekly Tuesday, biweekly Thursday.
Can anybody provide how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Sure,I have tried using joda time and also Calender code examples.

Comment: @hanmayya then post your code

Comment: What does biweekly Tuesday mean? If it means every other week, which week? Even numbered weeks in a standard ISO 8601 week-based year? Every second and fourth Tuesday of the month? Define your terms. Give examples.

Comment: public static LocalDate getLastWeekdayOfMonth(int dayweek, int month, int year) {
                                LocalDate d = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).plusMonths(1).withDayOfWeek(dayweek);
                                if (d.getMonthOfYear() != month)
                                                d = d.minusWeeks(1);
                                return d;
                }

Comment: private static Calendar cacheCalendar;

                public static LocalDate getNDayOfMonth(int dayweek, int nthweek, int month, int year) {
                                LocalDate d = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).withDayOfWeek(dayweek);
                                if (d.getMonthOfYear() != month)
                                                d = d.plusWeeks(1);
                                return d.plusWeeks(nthweek - 1);
                }

Answer (score 0):

private static Calendar cacheCalendar;

```
            public static LocalDate getNDayOfMonth(int dayweek, int nthweek, int month, int year) {
                            LocalDate d = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).withDayOfWeek(dayweek);
                            if (d.getMonthOfYear() != month)
                                            d = d.plusWeeks(1);
                            return d.plusWeeks(nthweek - 1);
            }

            public static LocalDate getLastWeekdayOfMonth(int dayweek, int month, int year) {
                            LocalDate d = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).plusMonths(1).withDayOfWeek(dayweek);
                            if (d.getMonthOfYear() != month)
                                            d = d.minusWeeks(1);
                            return d;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                            cacheCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                                            // second wednesday of oct-2011

                                            LocalDate secondMonday = getNDayOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY, 2, i, cacheCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                            System.out.println("secondMonday= " + secondMonday);

                                            LocalDate secondTuesday = getNDayOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY, 2, i,
                                                                            cacheCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                            System.out.println("secondTuesday= " + secondTuesday);

                                            LocalDate monthlyTuesday = getNDayOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY, 1, i,
                                                                            cacheCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                            System.out.println("monthlyTuesday= " + monthlyTuesday);                                                

                                            LocalDate weeklyFirstFriday = getNDayOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY, 1, i,
                                                                            cacheCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                                            System.out.println("weeklyFirstFriday= " + weeklyFirstFriday);                                                


                            }                                
            }
```